# Android app to record video with screen off

Tags: gratis, android, video, camera

I need to use my phone as a dash-camera on my car.

If the screen is on it will be distracting, and also waste battery (the car charger barely keeps up when the phone is being used for navigation).

So, what is the best free option for recording?

Comment: I've heard about this app but never tried. See if it meets your requirement. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeronoiseapps.secretvideorecorder&hl=en

Comment: [This answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/35169/60) to the question [*Android app to record audio/video without showing on screen*](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35123/60) seems to be relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app to record audio/video without showing on screen](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35123/android-app-to-record-audio-video-without-showing-on-screen)